# Can I add a second 4GB DDR3 RAM on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, ramdisk

I have 4GB **DDR3L** RAM on my laptop according to my laptop's information provided by the brand's website. But when I checked using command on Ubuntu 20.04, it shows this is **ddr3** ram. Now, my question is: can I add a second 4GB DDR3 RAM on my laptop or I have to add a ddr3l ram on my laptop?

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Go to www.crucial.com and scan your computer.

Comment: DDR3L runs at 1.35v, and as the Ubuntu image shows, the Minimum Voltage is 1.35V